# How to get all data from results axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios

So I set up a simple API so I can mess around with Vue.js but I'm not quite understanding how axios works. It's returning the data from the API, but I'm not sure how to handle the data.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        info: null
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      axios
        .get('http://localhost:8000/foods/')
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.info = response.data
        })

    }
  })
```

The response looks like this

```
{"count":4,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"url":"http://localhost:8000/foods/1/","food_name":"Pizza","country_of_origin":"Italy"},{"url":"http://localhost:8000/foods/2/","food_name":"Curry","country_of_origin":"India"},{"url":"http://localhost:8000/foods/3/","food_name":"Stew","country_of_origin":"United Kingdom"},{"url":"http://localhost:8000/foods/4/","food_name":"Bratwurst","country_of_origin":"Germany"}]}
```

I've tried `this.info = response.data.results[0].food_name` but that doesn't seem right. How do I output everything in the `result` part of the response? Or am I missing something completely?

Comment: Your code seems to work. `response.data.results[0].food_name` will return `Pizza`.
If you want everything in the `results` part you just need to say : `this.info = response.data.results ` and `this.info` will now be an array containing the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first at all you are knowing the response wrong

because your `response.data` looks like:

```
{
"count": 4,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/foods/1/",
    "food_name": "Pizza",
    "country_of_origin": "Italy"
}, {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/foods/2/",
    "food_name": "Curry",
    "country_of_origin": "India"
}, {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/foods/3/",
    "food_name": "Stew",
    "country_of_origin": "United Kingdom"
}, {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/foods/4/",
    "food_name": "Bratwurst",
    "country_of_origin": "Germany"
}]
}
```

I think if you use `this.info = response.data.results` you will get

```
[{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/foods/1/",
    "food_name": "Pizza",
    "country_of_origin": "Italy"
}, {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/foods/2/",
    "food_name": "Curry",
    "country_of_origin": "India"
}, {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/foods/3/",
    "food_name": "Stew",
    "country_of_origin": "United Kingdom"
}, {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/foods/4/",
    "food_name": "Bratwurst",
    "country_of_origin": "Germany"
}]
```

If you use  `this.info = response.data.results[n]` (n = any number in the array len), for example  `this.info = response.data.results[0]` you will get

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/foods/1/",
    "food_name": "Pizza",
    "country_of_origin": "Italy"
}
```

I recommend whenever you do not know the object, give a print of it and try to go through the elements of it individually

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer before I posted mine. I'll accept yours since it's the same thing and you had it first.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Better to store results in an array using `response.data.results`

```
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data () {
          return {
            info: []
          }
        },
        mounted () {
          axios
            .get('http://localhost:8000/foods/')
            .then(response => {
              this.info = response.data.results
            })

        }
      })
```